# Fix color scale in openair::polarPlot()

Tags: r, lattice, openair

Is there a way to fix the colour scale so it remains the same, for instance when producing multiple plots? I know once can use `polarPlot(..., type = "year")` but I don't want a grid of graphs as I'm trying to create an animation (I have cross-listed this question under the Github repo [issues](https://github.com/davidcarslaw/openair/issues/269)).

```
library(openair)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

polarPlot(filter(mydata, year(date) == 1999),
          pollutant = "nox")

polarPlot(filter(mydata, year(date) == 2004),
          pollutant = "nox")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The author of the package suggests one can set the limits in the options e.g. `limits = c(0, 300)`.  Full answer:

https://github.com/davidcarslaw/openair/issues/269